# Верстка блоков схожих с таблицей

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими средствами можно верстать приведенные выше блоки и им подобные, с помощью таблиц или есть некоторые другие варианты?

Comment: можно и блочной версткой это сделать

Comment: Евгений Николаев ок, спасибо когда вопрос задавал, модно сделать с помощью ul ?

Comment: Евгений Николаев ок, спасибо когда вопрос задавал, подумал можно сделать с помощью ul ?

Comment: Все зависит от задачи, если это только десктоп, то можно и таблицей, если же предусмотрен адаптив, то есть несколько различных вариантов решения. Например https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=responsive%20table&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false , в частности - https://codepen.io/zavoloklom/pen/IGkDz

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения табличных данных предназначены.. **таблицы!**
Так что берёшь обычную табличку и всё.

---

> скажите пожалуйста пользователь Евгений Бабийчук написал, что можно на div или grid использовать, у вас большой рейтинг, скажите пожалуйста ваше мнение

div - это вообще разметка, а не стили. В принципе, любые элементы можно заменить на div, если прописать соответствующие стили. Впрочем, он имел в виду не div'ы, а классическую блочную вёрстку. Да можно, но только если ширина фиксированная. Если нет, то можно использовать flex'ы, но за синхронизацию столбцов отвечает разработчик. Css grid layout - штука довольно крутая, способна полностью заменить таблицы, но надо проверять поддержку браузерами. Ну и ещё раз - если что-то сделать можно, то это не означает, что это делать нужно